# My router is unable to connect to my pppoe connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, pppoe

I have a PPPOE connection and I am able to access internet by plugging Ethernet cable into the Ethernet port of any laptop but when my router tries connecting to internet via same credentials it shows me below error from the image, I have tried updating router’s firmware, rebooting and resetting the router. What can be the cause? Is my router broken?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you haven't set a PPPoE Service Name on your router, unless your ISP specifically requires it (and if so, copy and paste it so you get it exactly right). If you set a Service Name on your PPPoE client, PPPoE servers are not supposed to respond unless they've been configured to serve that exact Service Name. The most common PPPoE configuration error is people thinking they can fill in the Service Name however they want instead of leaving it blank.

Comment: I understand your point, well in my case neither my ISP specifies any service name nor I have set any. The only fields I have filled in the configuration panel is username and password. Which are correct as I am able to access the internet directly via Ethernet port of my laptop. Can there be any reason for the error or my router is broken?